# How to know actual working shift with php

Tags: php

I'm trying to identify the current work shift from 3 options (24 hour format)

- First shift 06:00 to 13:59
- Second shift 14:00 to 21:59
- Third shift 22:00 to 05:59

I tried this, but it's not working as expected

```
$hour = date("0500");
$shift;
if ($hour >= 0600 && $hour <= 1359 ) {
 $shift = 1;
}else if($hour >= 14 && $hour <= 2159 )
{
 $shift = 2;
}else
{
 $shift = 3;
}
```

Comment: What are you getting as a result?

Comment: your days have 1359 hours?

Comment: shift Id from a mysql table

Comment: checkout the [DataTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php). That is built for such tasks and makes it much easier to compare dates/times.

Comment: I shearched for an example here and found things like this :"1359" "2222" etc

Comment: and this `$hour = date("0500");` is completely useless. You could just say `$hour = "0500";`. It's just a string here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
$hour = data('H');
if($hour >= 6 && $hour < 14) {
    $shift = 1;
} else if($hour >= 14 && $hour < 22) {
    $shift = 2;
} else {
    $shift = 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this perhaps:

```
$hour = data('H');

switch( true ){
    case ( $hour >= 6 && $hours < 14 ):$shift=1; break;
    case ( $hour >=14 && $hour < 22 ):$shift=2; break;
    default: $shift=3; break;
}
```

Comment: How can I add seconds to the hour variable to be 24 hour format and compare that in your code

Comment: do you really need seconds? if the current time was for example 13.59.59 then the int value `13` is still less than 14, but when the clock ticks over and the time is 14.00.00 the condition is no longer valid so I'm not sure you need the second as such

Comment: sorry im not that good at this but it you think so Its fine for me you seem to have more experience than me

Comment: but I would like to have minutes if thats ok or could work for you

Answer (score 0):

Put your time in quotes otherwise starting with 0 makes it an octal number
Also stick with one format if you are going to be comparing

```
$hour = date("Hi", strtotime("05:00"));
$shift;
if ($hour >= "0600" && $hour <= "1359" ) {
    $shift = 1;
}else if($hour >= "1400" && $hour <= "2159" ) {
    $shift = 2;
}else {
    $shift = 3;
}
```

Comment: I put 0500 as example to show my code its not working but the $hour variable should be equal to (Hours minutes and if possible seconds)

Comment: oh then i didnt need to comment out the date function. you can use it and pass in any acceptable datetime format

Comment: [valid time formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php) include 0530, 05:30, 05.30.12, etc